# How to use dynamic_cast to downcast correctly?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast

I am being very confused about `dynamic_cast`. Material from *C++ Primer* and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)(rule 5) can't help me understand. (cppreference is way much harder than the book and I read them both very carefully)

From *C++ Primer 5th*:
`dynamic_cast<type*>(e)`

> In all cases, the type of `e` must be either a class type that is publicly derived from the target type, a `public` base class of the target type, or the same as the target type. If `e` has one of these types, then the cast will succeed...

So here's how I understand the quoted text above:

(Base class have virtual functions)

`dynamic_cast` succeeds if :

1. `e` is a public inherited derived class from `type`.  `e` is children. Upcast.
2. `e` is a base class of `type`? `type` is children. Downcast.
3. `e` is same as `type`. Sidecast?

---

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {}
};

struct B : A {

};

struct C : B {

};

int main()
{
    A* pa = new B;
    if (C* pc = dynamic_cast<C*>(pa)) {
        cout << "1";    //B is a base class of C
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this downcast would fail, I think it satisfies *condition 2.* and *rule 5)* (from cppreference).

---

If the book is wrong(damn once again), would someone elaborate [rule 5)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) from cppreference? I can't fully understand what it say without examples...

Comment: That quote is wrong. `dynamic_cast` can cast across class hierarchy; the source and target types may be unrelated to each other (there may be a third class derived from both of them).

Comment: A `B` is not a `C`.

Comment: When types are being discussed here, they're referring ***to the actual object*** being casted. Your actual object is `B`. It is not `C`. Basically, the object being dynamic casted has to have a `C` "somewhere in it", in a manner of speaking. This is not true here. P.S. That quote is wrong also, true, what Igor said.

Comment: If `e` is a pointer to the same type as `type`, the cast is simply a no-op.

Comment: The C++ Primer is simply being wrong (again). But what are *your* expectations from this cast? Do you hope a `C` object will appear out of thin air so that the result of the cast could point to it?

Comment: "the type of `e` must be ... a class type" Whoa right there. In the syntax shown, the type of `e` should be a *pointer* to a class type. Frankly, that quote makes no sense; it's irredeemably wrong.

Comment: Here is an accurate (to my knowledge) [specification of `dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I read rule 5) ( I think that's the most related one). But I just don't understand...

Comment: The very page you have linked has an example.

Comment: Yes, although cppreference tries to be easier to read than the Standard, it often has the problem that being completely correct in all cases just requires being complicated.

Comment: @n.m. The example is almost useless... I came across this question from the section exercise. I made myself a similar sample code.

Comment: The "...correctly?" qualifier makes me want to point out that better code does not need to use dynamic_cast at all.  Needing dynamic_cast is a bad, bad code smell.

Comment: The example tells you everything you need to know about the *downcast*. It doesn't illustrate *sidecast* but your question isn't about it either.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the rule from cppreference with my annotations:

> 5) If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base,
>   and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time
>   check is performed:

This applies. `B` is a base of `C`.

> a) The most derived object pointed/identified by
>   expression is examined. If, in that object, expression points/refers
>   to a public base of Derived, and if only one subobject of Derived type
>   is derived from the subobject pointed/identified by expression, then
>   the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived subobject. (This
>   is known as a "downcast".)

The most dervied object pointed by `pa` is of type `B`.

Although `B` is a public base of `C`, the particular instance which `pa` points to, is not an instance of `B` base subobject of a `C` instance. The pointed `B` instance is a "concrete" object. So, this case does not apply.

An example:

```
C  c;
B* bp = &c; // bp points to base subobject of C
C* cp = dynamic_cast<C*>(bp);
assert(cp);

B  b2;
B* bp2 = &b2; // bp does not point to a base subobject
C* cp2 = dynamic_cast<C*>(bp2);
assert(!cp2);
```

> b) Otherwise, if expression points/refers
>   to a public base of the most derived object, and, simultaneously, the
>   most derived object has an unambiguous public base class of type
>   Derived, the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived (This is
>   known as a "sidecast".)

`pa` does not point to a most derived object whose base class is `C`, so this case does not apply.

An example of side cast:

```
struct base {
    virtual ~base(){}; // for polymorphism
};
struct left : base {};
struct right : base {};
struct derived : left, right {};

derived d;
left* l = &d;
right* r = dynamic_cast<right*>(l);
```

> c) **Otherwise, the runtime check fails**. If the
>   dynamic_cast is used on pointers, **the null pointer value of type
>   new_type is returned**. If it was used on references, the exception
>   std::bad_cast is thrown.

Neither 5a nor 5b cases apply, so this "otherwise" case 5c does.

---

> 3. e is same as type. Sidecast?

Not a sidecast. A sidecast is explained in 5b. Casting to same type is just an identity cast (rarely useful, so not a commonly used terminology either).

---

It may be that the conditions of the book attempt describe whether the conversion is well-formed. Although, *"then the cast will succeed"* certainly seems to imply more. The quoted rules are **not** correct for describing whether the cast succeeds at runtime.

If the entire program is well-formed, then a compiler must compile the program. If an expression is ill-formed, then a compiler must give you a diagnostic message saying that you did wrong.

The example program that you've shown is well-formed and it must successfully compile. It does compile on my system.

Comment: I read that rule very carefully and know it fails. The point is that I don't understand what a) and b) are talking about at all. My understanding are mostly based on guessing the meaning of a) and b).

Comment: @Rick I added explanations.

Comment: Nice answer, but just to be clear: In a "side cast", only the source type *must* be polymorphic. The (static) target type just has to be an unambiguous public base class of the most derived class, whether it's polymorphic or not.

Comment: Thank you for providing more details. But I still don't understand rule a) fully. Why saying *"is not an instance of B base subobject of a C instance."*? I think B is a base subobject of C... After all, C inheris from B. What do I get wrong?

Comment: `A`, `B` and `C` are not an objects. They are classes. Instances of classes are objects. Instances of `B` have an `A` base subobject. Instances of `C` have a `B` base subobject. `pa` does not point to a base subobject of a `C` instance. It cannot be, since you don't ever create any `C` objects in your program. `pa` just happens to point to an object that is of same type (that type being `B`).

Comment: @Rick how about a car analogy: Think of a `B` being "steering wheel", and `C` being "car". Now, it is silly to think the wheel being base of the car, but as long as we just think of it as a sub-object, it should be fine. So, a car has a sub object wheel. Think of your dynamic cast as asking for the car which the wheel is attached to. So, you've created a steering wheel (`new B`), and then ask for the car which the wheel is attached to (the cast)... but you haven't created any cars and the lonely steering wheel isn't attached to any.

Comment: @user2079303 :P. Do you mind spending a few mins on chat.. when you are free?

Answer (score 3):

The last part is that the dynamic type of the object must match.

Here, you have a `B` pointed to by an `A` pointer.  You are trying to dynamically cast the pointer to get a pointer to `C`, but there is no `C` to point to.  So the cast fails.

dynamic cast doesn't create objects, it just lets you access objects that are already there.  When you call `new B` it creates a `B` object with an `A` subobject.  It does not create a `C` object.

Comment: Hmmm. That makes sense. Then why it has something called *downcast*? I mean, there's no actual `Base` type to `Derived` type casting here and should not happen logically.

Comment: So *downcast* mentioned by cppreference is merely saying that it is the *pointer* that is "downcasting"?

Comment: @Rick The class heirarchy exists regardless.  Typically we put the base classes above the derived classes when we draw a class heirarchy graph.  Then "down" here refers to "to a location lower in the drawing" (usually with "oh, and with a line of descent connecting).  "cross" cast is left-to-right where one isn't above another (no line of descent).  And "up" cast goes up the graph towards the top.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the statement `A* pa = new B;` creates a `B`.

But a `B` doesn't contain a `C` (downwards, upwards, or sideways), so the dynamic cast from `pa` to a `C*` will certainly fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm, for the most part, adding another example of a side cast to previous answers…

```
struct A {};
struct B { virtual ~B() = default; };
struct C : A, B {};

A *side_cast()
{
    B *obj = new C;
    return dynamic_cast<A *>(obj);
}
```

The above is a legal "side cast", and does not return null. This shows that the target type *neither*:

- has to be polymorphic.
- has to be related to the static type of `*`*expression*.

for the cast to *succeed at run time*.

The cast is *well-formed*, regardless of whether the type of the most-derived object pointed to by *expression* (IOW, the dynamic type of `*`*expression*)  inherits from the target type. However, it will return `static_cast<A *>(nullptr)` unless `A` is a *public and unambiguous* base class of the dynamic type of `*`*expression*. The gist of this is that you can legally write a whole bunch of nonsensical casts like `dynamic_cast<std::tuple<int, float> *>(&std::cin)` – note that `std::cin` is of type `std::istream` which is polymorphic –, but you'll simply get a null pointer at runtime.

Simply put, a `dynamic_cast` between pointers can do most of the things that a `static_cast` can (except, at least, non-polymorphic downcast*), and, when the static type of `*`*expression* is polymorphic, it can also cast to any pointer to class whatsoever, except for removing *cv-qualifers* (`const` or `volatile`). However, whether the cast actually returns non-null depends on the specific condition, checked at run time, mentioned above.

<sub>* The reason why this is forbidden is that there is no safe way to do this, and `dynamic_cast` is expected to be safe. Hence they make you write `static_cast` to make it clear that any ensuing UB is your fault.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add my two cents on top of @eerorika 's fabulous answer, primarily focusing on the phrase of

> If only one object of Derived type is derived from the subobject pointed/identified by an expression, then....

I think this is to prevent downcasting given the following condition:

```
           Base  
             |
          Derived
          /      \
         |        V 
         |      Right
          \      /
           V    V
         MostDerived
```

In this case, there 2 objects of Derived in MostDerived. Upon casting a Base pointer, which points to a MostDerived instance, to a Derived pointer, it is impossible for the compiler to know which of the Derived object one's referring to. (The one that is referred by MostDerived or the one that's referred by Right.)

In fact, this is the exact case of ambiguous base access and will cause compiler warning or failed compilation depends on your implementation.